# How do I identify rows with duplicates when all columns are dummy variables?

Tags: r, duplicates, dummy-variable

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 
   1     0     0
   0     1     0
   1     0     0
   1     0     1
   0     1     1
```

I want to return the following data frame:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
   1     0     1
   0     1     1
```

That is, I want each row with more than one instance of "1"

I am having difficulty because when using the duplicated function, it is returning the instances where there are multiple values = 0, meaning that each row from the original data frame would be included in the new data frame (not what I want)

Comment: does `rowSums(x) > 1` do what you want?

Comment: Expanding on @dww: `df[rowSums(df) > 1, ]`, where `df` is your data.frame.

Comment: Removing duplicates would give you rows 1,2,4 and 5. What you're filtering on doesn't sound like duplication. I think the comments above are what you want. And one of you 2 commenters should make it into an official answer.

Comment: yes, sorry rowsums(x) > 1 works exactly how I want it

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
df[rowSums(df) > 1, ]
```